# SQL Server Permission

Tags: sql-server

Is it harmful to add `<domain>\Domain Users` on SQL Server at the server level logins but don't grant them permission on any object? I just want to know more about how security works on SQL Server so please don't ask me why would I want to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server configuration/permissions are offtopic.

Comment: What you are asking is,'Is it harmful to give people keys to the main house if they cant get into any rooms.' I would not.

Comment: Add what you need to no more no less. When you start working with security standards such as PCI-DSS explaining to an auditor why you granted a non-authorized user a login can be tiresome. The more openings you have for an attach the higher your risk. So limit this by just adding people that needs access.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a security concern if you do it correctly.

I would take a look at [Microsoft Security Best Practices](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/F/A/8FABACD7-803E-40FC-ADF8-355E7D218F4C/SQL_Server_2012_Security_Best_Practice_Whitepaper_Apr2012.docx) if security is a concern.  There are many pitfalls you can fall into if you are unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

It's a vulnerability, which makes it potentially harmful.  By default, any users with the minimum role (public) can see a lot of server-level specifications, including properties of every database on the server.  A hacker could use this information to more easily exploit another security loophole you may have.

They also have access to run queries which could:

1. Cause resource contention on disk, network, etc
2. Consume all CPU on the server
3. Consume all RAM on the server
4. Max out tempDB, which could max out the server's hard drive if tempDB has no limit

Any of these things could cause slowness, timeouts, or even downtime for applications which depend on the SQL Server.

If this is a dev server, you might not be concerned by anything in this list.  If this is a production server which people depend on to do their jobs, it's not worth taking any risks.